# Ionic 3 - *ngIf binding not updating when condition changes

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I currently trying to develop my own custom component and having issues trying to get the component to show when a boolean condition changes to true.

I have tried using "**ChangeDetectorRef**" and use "**detectChanges()**" after changing the boolean status. Unfortunately, I keep getting provider error:

> Error: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!

I have used changeRef in pages with no issue. I really don't understand why it needs provider for a component when its suppose to be built into Ionic modules by default?

I have also tried using changeRef.detectChange() on the page instead, there is no provider error - but the component still does not show.

**Custom component:**

```
import { Component, Injectable, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'options-popup',
      templateUrl: 'options-popup.html'
    })

    @Injectable()
    export class OptionsPopup {

        public showOptionsMenu:Boolean = false;
        public optionsMenu: {
            header:string,
            options: { iconURL: any, label:string, tapAction: string }[]
        };

        constructor( private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {

        }

        public create( optionsMenu: { header:string, options: { iconURL: any, label:string,
                tapAction: string }[] } ){

            this.optionsMenu = optionsMenu;
        }

        public present(){

            this.showOptionsMenu = true;

            this.changeRef.detectChanges();

            console.log("present clicked - set to " + this.showOptionsMenu);
        }

        public dismiss(){
            this.showOptionsMenu = false;
            // this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        }

    }
```

**Component HTML:**

```
<div class="options-container" *ngIf="showOptionsMenu">
    <div class="options-header-wrapper"> Send Images to:</div>
    <div class="options-content" >

        <div class="options-item-wrapper" *ngFor="let option of optionsMenu.options">
            <div class="options-kiosk-icon" [style.background-image]="option.iconURL" 
            *ngIf="option.iconURL != null"></div>
             {{ option.label }}
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="options-cancel-wrapper">Back</div>
</div>

<div class="options-screen-overlay" *ngIf="showOptionsMenu"></div>
```

**Page using component:**

```
 public createSelectIKPopover(){    
        let options: { iconURL: any, label:string, tapAction: string }[] = [];    
        options.push( { iconURL: null, label: "IK01", tapAction: "" } );    
        this.optionsPopup.create( { header: "", options: options });    
        this.optionsPopup.present();    
        this.changeRef.detectChanges();
    }
```

Comment: `ChangeDetectorRef` can only be injected to components, not to services.

Comment: It's unclear where `showOptionsMenu` should come from that you use in the HTML. If you change it in the service, there is no reason why it should change in the view as well. Perhaps you assume that when you copy it somehwere (components constructor) that it will be updated automatically, but copies are not connected.

Comment: I think it should be `public showOptionsMenu: boolean = false;` not `public showOptionsMenu: Boolean = false;`.

Comment: Why is `@Injectable()` used as a decorator above `export class OptionsPopup` if it's a component ?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, Thanks I see what you mean now that you explain it. I was only using it as service to access the methods.  I guess I would have to separate the service from the component or just use `let component = app.getComponenent('OptionsPopup')` to access its methods. I was originally trying create a component similar to ionic native components (injected as service)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the the Angular service ngZone for this.

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.optionsMenu = optionsMenu;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put condition as `*ngIf="showOptionsMenu == true"` and check